# How convert "2022-10-26T00:00:00.654199+00:00" timeformat to unix

Tags: sql, datetime, time, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I need convert string `2022-10-26T00:00:00.654199+00:00`
to Unix timestamp, is it possible with clickhouse?

```sql
    toUnixTimestamp64Milli(visitParamExtractString(msg, 'time'))
```

where `time` is `2022-10-26T00:00:00.654199+00:00`

This way it doesn't work.

Comment: DB is clickhouse, client for queries is Dbeaver

Comment: also i tried just a 
toUnixTimestamp(visitParamExtractString(msg , 'time'))

Comment: and receive an error: 
SQL Error [6] [07000]: Code: 6. DB::Exception: Received from clickhouse-3.mgt:9000. DB::Exception: Cannot parse string '2022-10-26T00:00:00.654199+00:00' as UInt32: syntax error at position 19 (parsed just '2022-10-26T00:00:00'). Note: there are toUInt32OrZero and toUInt32OrNull functions, which returns zero/NULL instead of throwing exception.: while executing 'FUNCTION toUnixTimestamp(visitParamExtractString(msg, 'time') :: 4) -> toUnixTimestamp(visitParamExtractString(msg, 'time')) UInt32 : 3'. (CANNOT_PARSE_TEXT) (version 22.4.5.9 (official build))

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```sql
SELECT
    json,
    JSONExtractString(json, 'time') AS time,
    parseDateTime64BestEffort(time, 6) AS dt,
    toUnixTimestamp64Milli(dt) AS ts
FROM 
(
    WITH [
        '{"time": "2022-10-26T00:00:00.654199+00:00"}',
        '{"time": "2022-10-26T00:00:00.654199+08:00"}'] AS jsons
    SELECT arrayJoin(jsons) AS json
)

/*
┌─json─────────────────────────────────────────┬─time─────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────dt─┬────────────ts─┐
│ {"time": "2022-10-26T00:00:00.654199+00:00"} │ 2022-10-26T00:00:00.654199+00:00 │ 2022-10-26 00:00:00.654199 │ 1666742400654 │
│ {"time": "2022-10-26T00:00:00.654199+08:00"} │ 2022-10-26T00:00:00.654199+08:00 │ 2022-10-25 16:00:00.654199 │ 1666713600654 │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┴───────────────┘
*/
```